# How to check when a dhcp IP was released?

Tags: powershell, dhcp

My DHCP server is 2008R2. I was wondering that if there is any way to know the release date and time for a given DHCP IP address?

I see there is a command "get-dhcpserverv4lease", but it only exists on Win 10 and Server 2016.

How can I know it on 2008R2 or 2012R2?

Comment: you can use `ipconfig /all` and parse the output. there is a line that starts with `Lease Expires` ... [*grin*]

Comment: the client is an unknown device, not a windows for sure.

Comment: ah! that is rather different. have you looked at the various CIM/WMI classes yet? another possible way is `netsh dhcp server dump` - got that from here ... How to query DHCP Lease Duration information? — https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windowsserver/en-US/5f90d894-0cd4-4810-b816-c6c46b1b07f6/how-to-query-dhcp-lease-duration-information

Answer (score 1):

You can use WMI oder netsh.

**WMI**

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\DHCP -List | Where-Object Name -eq 'DhcpServerv4Lease'
```

Unfortunately I cannot validate this WMI query, because I only have a Windows Server 2016 DHCP server and it is returning an empty object there. However, the `PS_DhcpServerv4IPLease` class is working fine on 2016.

**NETSH**

You need to parse the output and iterate throug all scopes

```
netsh dhcp server \\dhcpservername show scope

==============================================================================
 Scope Address  - Subnet Mask    - State        - Scope Name          -  Comment
==============================================================================

 192.168.178.0  - 255.255.255.0  -Active        -Default IPv4 Scope   -

 Total No. of Scopes = 1
Command completed successfully.
```

Then through all IP-Addresses

```
C:\Windows\system32>netsh dhcp server \\dhcpservername scope 192.168.178.0 show clients

Changed the current scope context to 192.168.178.0 scope.

Type : N - NONE, D - DHCP B - BOOTP, U - UNSPECIFIED, R - RESERVATION IP
==================================================================================
IP Address      - Subnet Mask    - Unique ID           - Lease Expires        -Type
==================================================================================

192.168.178.170 - 255.255.255.0  - b0-72-bf-cb-97-a0   -25.04.2019 18:56:41    -D
192.168.178.171 - 255.255.255.0  - 00-0d-2f-d5-b1-d6   -25.04.2019 12:03:38    -D
192.168.178.172 - 255.255.255.0  - b0-4e-26-72-9b-5f   -19.04.2019 23:08:19    -D
192.168.178.173 - 255.255.255.0  - 70-4f-57-11-01-03   -20.04.2019 23:00:00    -D

No of Clients(version 4): 4 in the Scope : 192.168.178.0.

Command completed successfully.
```

Answer (score 1):

Sebastian Segerer, netsh dhcp server only works up to windows 8.1....beyond that there is no netsh DHCP SERVER ...only netsh dhcpclient and it wont get what you would need.

so if you have windows 10 it wont work, or 2008 R2 or 2012 or 2016.